There is a typo in Stall's textbook on Set Theory: unable to prove the trichotomy of sets (m ∈ n or m = n, or n ∈ m)



Here is the textbook, chapter 7, page 300. This lemma seems very of important, and I've spend about 8 hours trying to figure it out, but I'm unable to prove even the weaker version of the lemma (only the disjunctions). I've also tried to use the induction, but to result. I see there is a logical gap which seems impossible to feel.
I've checked another book on set theory (by Thomas Jech) which seems more modern and advanced, but it doesn't seem to cover it. I also aware of Terrence Tao Analysis I, he gives quite a complicated proof of trichotomy of naturals. He uses the plus function which needs to be additionally defined and his definitions are also slightly different.
Is there a way to prove trichotomy on sets without extra overcomplications? Or maybe you confirm it is a typo in the textbook and I should seek a not of easy matter proof...

This can be proven quickly for all ordinals when defined as heredetarily membership transitive sets, and natural numbers are just finite ordinals.

Going from "one of the possibilities holds" to "exactly one of the possibilities holds" does not need any argument related to how natural numbers are defined: all combinations of two of the possibilities contradict the axiom of regularity/foundation.
